# organizing strings before joining them to create a common room

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a chat app where users chat in rooms. I want to insert both user uid strings into the function and return one concatenated string.
But I want the uids to be organized in a way so that the returned value is always the same.

```
func (id1, id2) -> id1id2
func (id2, id1) -> id1id2
```

Is there a higher order function in swift that solves that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id1` and `id2` are strings, you can use `<` operator.

for example:

```
let id1 = "id1"
let id2 = "id2"

func conString(str1: String, str2: String) -> String {
    if str1 < str2 {
        return str1+str2
    }
    return str2+str1
}
```